# How to pass a function as method parameter in java when I can not change the original function

Tags: java, android

I have found a lot of answers about this question but all of them says that we have to first change the function definition or create an interface for the function (or similar things)

My use case is this, I am extending an external `Plugin` class that has a protected method `notifyListeners`

```java
  /**
   * Notify all listeners that an event occurred
   * This calls {@link Plugin#notifyListeners(String, JSObject, boolean)}
   * with retainUntilConsumed set to false
   * @param eventName
   * @param data
   */
  protected void notifyListeners(String eventName, JSObject data) {
    notifyListeners(eventName, data, false);
  }
```

I have a function in another class that does some work that for the nature of it, can not return the end value (I can not change this) so I want to take `notifyListeners` (`this:: notifyListeners`) as a parameter into that class function but I can not find how to define that. I tried with `Function<T, R>` but it does not take void as a return parameter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the [BiConsumer Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

BiConsumer<String, JSObject>